# Set JLabel icon in Synth xml

Tags: java, swing, synth

I am trying to set the icon for a JLabel in a synth xml file but it does not display. I have tried to set both the defaultIcon and icon properties and none seem to be taking. Should I be using something other than a JLabel here? Here's my code:

```
 <style id="dayBgLabelStyle">
     <imageIcon id="bg" path="images/WG_selectionFields-2.png"/>
     <property key="defaultIcon" value="bg"/>
     <property key="icon" value="bg"/>
 </style>

 <bind style="dayBgLabelStyle" type="name" key="dayBgLabel"/>

JLabel dayBgLabel = new JLabel();
dayBgLabel.setName("dayBgLabel");
dayBgLabel.setIcon(createImageIcon("images/selectionFields-2.png"));

protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
    java.net.URL imgURL = testClass.class.getResource(path);
    if (imgURL != null)
        return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
    else
        return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the binding line for the synth style you created?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but maybe it helps someone else.

I managed to add an image by using

`<imagePainter  path="images/WG_selectionFields-2.png"" sourceInsets="1 1 5 5" />`

instead of using imageIcon. I hope this helps!